# defining field in z={ field : 'value'} using variable?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 'this';
```

I want

```
var z = { a: 'that' } === { 'this': 'that'}
```

where as:-

```
alert( z.this); // output is 'undefined'

alert(z.a); // output is 'that'
```

how do you define z's field using a variable?

So that...

```
alert( z.this); // output becomes 'that'
```

Use Case: dynamically create object `z`, instead of hardcoding its fields.

Comment: Question is not clear, could you provide a real world example of what you're trying to do? Why would you expect anything other than `undefined`? Why would you create a property called `this`?

Comment: I can't get what you actually want to do ... At least I can say that to me `z.this` does not make any sense `:/`

Comment: i want to dynamically create the JSON. My actual use case is a bit complex. but take for example: i want to create a field of JSON based on user input.

Comment: Give an example of input and output, it's not clear exactly what you're asking. Also, when you say JSON, do you mean literally JSON format? Because that's not JSON...

Comment: still not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you  codee there is no property `this` for object `z` this is why `alert(z.this)` shows  shows undefined. you must not use this as a property name as it is a reserved key word.

i think you need to define it like this

```
var a = 'this';
z[a]="that";
alert( z[a]); // output is 'that'
```

Comment: you might want to say alert(z.this); ?